# Can I configure and use 2 DHCP servers in my Home Lab Setup

Tags: virtualization, dhcp, esxi

I am setting up a Home Lab environment for development and testing. The purpose of this lab is multifunctional and the hardware involved is :

- Cisco ESW 540 24 Port GB Switch with VLAN etc...
- HP Proliant DL365 with 2 75GB and 1 100GB 10k SAS Drives
- NetApp FAS 250 NAS
- 3 Average Desktops with 2 or 4 cores and at least 4GB RAM Each

I am currently running 2008r2 on the HP Server and vCenter, ESXI on the 3 Desktops and have 2 luns on seperate aggregates on the NAS.

I would like to use the auto deploy feature in vSphere to provision the esxi hosts but have a problem because my home LAN uses a BT Home Hub 3 as the main gateway and DHCP server. I could disable DHCP on the Home Hub and run DHCP on the HP server, but I would like my lab setup to be able to be shutdown when im not using it - (these devices use a lot of power...)

So the crux of my question is, is it possible to somehow use some clever VLAN'ing to enable me to use Auto Deploy in my lab without disabling DHCP on the Home Hub?

(Some more background : I live in a shared house so I need to keep the Home LAN running OK while I am working on my Lab. The hardware is my garage, connected to the LAN using a Power Line adapter. I would like to use my main workstation to connect to and work with this Lab setup but I also want my workstation on the LAN at the same time for internet access etc...)

EDIT : I should have mentioned that the HP Server has 2 physical network adapters, so does the NAS - currently the desktop machines only have 1 physical adapter. This may help to run DHCP on a VLAN?

Comment: This question: http://serverfault.com/questions/368512/can-i-have-multiple-dhcp-servers-on-one-network has a lot about this topic (see first answer).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't really answer my question. After reading the post im not sure if what I want to do is possible or not. It talks about two different DHCP servers but they are both customizable (not a home hub).

Comment: I'm not very experienced with BT home hubs, sorry, I didn't really notice that bit.